# QGIS Reclassify by Table With Expression

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler, reclassify, qgis-expression

With QGIS Reclassify by Table I am trying to reclassify a raster within a model with a formula that uses statistics from the raster layer I want to reclassify. The formulae I am trying to recreate are:

Class 1 = values less than (mean - (1.5*Std_Dev))
Class 2 = values greater than (mean + (2.5*StdDev))

I used the following expression:

```
CASE WHEN 
 @Flood_Dry_Difference_Image_With_Slope_or_HAND_mask_OUTPUT   <= ( @Flood_Dry_Difference_Image_with_slope_or_HAND_mask_statistics_MEAN -(1.5* @Flood_Dry_Difference_Image_with_slope_or_HAND_mask_statistics_STD_DEV ))
  THEN '1'
 WHEN Flood_Dry_Difference_Image_With_Slope_or_HAND_mask_OUTPUT   >=  ( @Flood_Dry_Difference_Image_with_slope_or_HAND_mask_statistics_MEAN +(2.5* @Flood_Dry_Difference_Image_with_slope_or_HAND_mask_statistics_STD_DEV ))
then '2'
 END
```

I just get a rather vague 'Error encountered while running.....'

I'm using QGIS 3.28.5